# Why is a 8-bit 1-band raster with colour table larger than a 8-bit 3-band raster?

Tags: raster

I have been experimenting with GDAL in order to reduce the size of GeoTIFF files. All things being the same...which in this case means, with 2000x2000 Pixels at 0,5 m resolution per pixel, I would have naively thought that a 8-bit 1-band raster with Deflate compression would take up less disk space than an 8-bit 3-band raster with Deflate compression, but in fact it is at least 3 times the size. Nodata is not defined. Is this due to the fact that each pixel is now carrying an A-R-G-B 8-bit value whereas a 3-band raster only carries R-G-B?

Comment: What compression do you use for RBG and paletted TIFFs?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to a answer this without more information. A twenty band image with all NODATA might take fewer bytes than this comment. Different compression schemes have different benefits based on the data being compressed, and monochromatic images often have smaller pixel sizes than their multispectral brethren (same CCD density, different purpose).

Comment: Could you share test data?